# Access to a shared notebook using microsoft graph's API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I found it no way to find the notebook's id shared in my team using Microsoft Graph API. How can I update content in a shared location in out team..?

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks 
This only gives back the notebook created by me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of workaround ways you can do this:

- Access the notebook via the individual who owns it: 
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/uid/onenote/notebooks
- Access the notebooks shared with your group:
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/gid/onenote/notebooks

Comment: From where we can get the uid and gid fields. Since when I get notebooks using api http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?includesharednotebooks=true

In the createdBy user field the id is coming as my id, not the user who has shared the notebook with me. This seems like a bug in onenote api